# Slack is not correctly formatting my JSON for a slash command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, slack, slack-api

I am setting up a custom slash command between Slack and Build kite using Ruby. I am getting the correct API calls and the information is being passed. Everything seems to be working but when I try to set up the json payload I receive I can not seem to use Slacks new formatting. I have it working with the old formatting but when I switch to new it breaks and just gives me a string.

I have tried parsing the json, ensuring it is valid, and using other methods like response.body.

This JSON will result in a string:

```
   [{
          "type":"section",
          "text":
              {
                "type":"mrkdwn",
                "text":"*Deploy History:* Deploys in the last 6 hours"
              }
    }]
```

This JSON will correctly be formatted:

```
  {
    text: "",
    attachments: [{
      title: 'Deploy History',
      text: 'Deploys in the last 6 hours',
      :fields => [{
        :title => 'Message',
        :value => build_list[0].message,
        :short => true
      }, {
        :title => 'Name',
        :value => build_list[0].creator.name,
        :short => true
      }, {
        :title => 'Finished at',
        :value => build_list[0].finished_at,
        :short => true
      }],
        color: 'good'
    }]
  }
```

The expected result of the first code would look nice and pretty but it just spits this out: {"type":"section","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"*Deploy History:* Deploys in the last six hours"}}]

The result of the working bottom code is nice and pretty

The file that is called when the slash command is sent

```
module SlackLine::Commands
  module DeployHistory extend self

    def deploy_history
      build_list = buildkite.process_history_event
      presenter.deploy_history(build_list)
    end

    def presenter
      SlackLine::Presenters::DeployHistoryPresenter
    end

    def buildkite
      SlackLine::Services::BuildkiteHistoryService
    end
  end
end
```

This is the file where we make the api call to buildkite

```
    def deploy_stats
      finished_from = 6.hours.ago.to_time.iso8601
      options = {
        branch: 'master',
        finished_from: finished_from,
        state: 'finished'
      }
      build_list = client.pipeline_builds('calendly', 'calendly', options)
      build_list
    end
```

Comment: HI there and welcome to SO. Please add the relevant part of your code to the question that is defining and sending the blocks style message to Slack.

Comment: Hey @ErikKalkoken thanks for the reply! This file is where we define what we want to be sent when using the slash command.

`module SlackLine::Commands
  module DeployHistory extend self

    def deploy_history
      build_list = buildkite.process_history_event
      presenter.deploy_history(build_list)
    end

    def presenter
      SlackLine::Presenters::DeployHistoryPresenter
    end

    def buildkite
      SlackLine::Services::BuildkiteHistoryService
    end
  end
end`

Comment: And this is where we get the api call
    `def deploy_stats
      finished_from = 6.hours.ago.to_time.iso8601
      options = {
        branch: 'master',
        finished_from: finished_from,
        state: 'finished'
      }
      build_list = client.pipeline_builds('calendly', 'calendly', options)
      build_list
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Can you please put your code in the question? Its really hard to read properly in the comments and do to limited formatting in comments also prone to errors. Thank you

Comment: Ahh I spending my time trying to figure out how to put a code block in the comment haha I will now sorry!

Comment: Alright finished!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! All I had to do was add a block. Thank you for bearing with me and I hope this helps someone out!

```
      {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "Deploys in the last six hours"
            }
          }
```